# How to add a new column in SQL db with grouped average of another column? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

| PostID | Uploader | Likes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | 18 |
| 2 | James | 20 |
| 3 | Johny | 28 |
| 4 | Johny | 30 |
| 5 | Rocky | 48 |
| 6 | Rocky | 68 |

I want to add a new column at the end which has the average number of likes of each post's uploader. So if James has average 19 likes, I want both rows 1 and 2 to have 19 in them.

I am trying this:

```
update mytable A
set    "AverageLikesOfUploader" = 
(
   select avg(B.Likes)
   from   mytable B
   group by B.Uploader
)
```

But it didn't work.

What should I do to get resultant this:

| PostID | Uploader | Likes | AverageLikesOfUploader |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | 18 | 19 |
| 2 | James | 20 | 19 |
| 3 | Johny | 28 | 29 |
| 4 | Johny | 30 | 29 |
| 5 | Rocky | 48 | 58 |
| 6 | Rocky | 68 | 58 |

Comment: Did you create the column? Or you only want the column in your select?

Comment: I have already created the column, it currently has null values. I want to add the column in the db, not just in select.

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So materializing an average from other values isn't a good thing to do. If you need the average, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: A non-key attribute cannot be dependent on another non-key attribute. It is generally a bad idea to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is right.

If you want a new column, after the update that you did, you have to distinct your results:

```
SELECT Uploader, AverageLikesOfUploader FROM yourtable GROUP BY Uploader, AverageLikesOfUploader
```

But in any case you have to still update your data everytime. It has no sense to me. Why do you want to save in a table a calculated value? I suggest you the following way:

If you don't want to create a new column:

```
SELECT 
Uploader, 
avg(B.Likes) as AverageLikesOfUploader
FROM
yourtable
GROUP BY Uploader
```

Comment: I edited my sql subquery to what you wrote in the first box, but I get this error: subquery must return only one column

Comment: @ssy I don't still understand why you want save that data in a new column.

Comment: I want a table where I can see each post's likes and the average likes together.

Comment: @ssy I understand, but you don't have to save the data in the table. The column will be obsolete with two more likes.

Comment: The db is static, it won't get updated. So once, the number of likes is recorded, it won't change.

Comment: @ssy anwyay, there is no reason to do that, only if you want to learn or waste space.

Comment: Actually I want to categorise each post as "High likes" and "Low likes" for some analysis. I thought of using python but the tool that I have only gives sql. I am looking for an sql query that can get this done. I understand pandas is a better tool, but right now, I have to get this done using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a relation between A and B in the query of the update statement.

```
update mytable A
set AverageLikesOfUploader = (
   select avg(B.Likes)
   from mytable B
   where B.Uploader = A.Uploader
)
```

| postid | uploader | likes | averagelikesofuploader |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | 18 | 19.00 |
| 2 | James | 20 | 19.00 |
| 3 | Johny | 28 | 29.00 |
| 4 | Johny | 30 | 29.00 |
| 5 | Rocky | 48 | 58.00 |
| 6 | Rocky | 68 | 58.00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9231489523fdda5b1b857b302f2bd2e9)*

Comment: this seems like what I wanted, unfortunately I am getting error: "An error occurred with your deployment". I'm doing this on a database hosted on supabase.

Comment: O_o wouldn't know about such problems. Good luck with getting it working again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use `avg` over a *window*

```
select *, Avg(likes) over(partition by uploader)::int AverageLikesOfUploader
from t
```

If you really want to update your table with the average (this is not a good idea, just use the above query to get the average) you can apply it with a CTE

```
with x as (
 select *, Avg(likes) over(partition by uploader) av
 from t
)
update t set AverageLikesOfUploader=av
from x
where x.PostId=t.PostId;
```

See [this demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3247ae62c58f976787e23544b54fbd70)